# Jasper Reports Polish characters

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

In my application i am using Jasper reports for generating the PDF reports.
The application supports multiple language as per the language of the logged in user. Polish is one of the supported language of the application.
The problem was that when the report was generated for Polish language characters like ŁOKIETKA were reduced to OKIETKA. 
I did search on web and found out that setting pdf encoding on the font to "Cp1252" or "Cp1250" should work this out.
However when i did the same the ŁOKIETKA started to show up however the character "Łączna" was getting printed to "Ł1czna" on the PDF viewer.
However when i copy paste that text here it shows that properly.
Not sure if that is the problem with the viewer.
When i open it on my mac it shows up properly but when it is opened in the browser pdf viewer it shows up 1.
Also setting this pdfencoding on the jrxml globally, will it have any impact on other languages which the application supports?

Any help on above is much appriciated.

-Vaibhav

Comment: Are you using font extensions?

Comment: Yes i am using Font Extension, the encoding "Identity-H" worked for these characters.